# airflow dag - task is immediately put into 'up_for_retry' state ('start_date' is 1 day ago)

Tags: celery, airflow, airflow-scheduler

I do not know if i am lack of airflow scheduler knowledge or if this is a potential bug from airflow.

situation is like this:

- my dag's start date is set to be `"start_date": airflow.utils.dates.days_ago(1),`
- i uploaded the dag to the folder where airflow scans the DAGs
- i then turn the dag on (it was by default 'off')
- the tasks in the pipeline immediately goes into 'up_for_retry' and you do not really see what had been tried before.
- airflow Version Info:  `Version : 1.10.14`. it is run on kubenetes in azure
- use Celery executor with Redis
- the task instance details are listed below:

```
Task Instance Details
Dependencies Blocking Task From Getting Scheduled
Dependency  Reason
Task Instance State Task is in the 'up_for_retry' state which is not a valid state for execution. The task must be cleared in order to be run.
Not In Retry Period Task is not ready for retry yet but will be retried automatically. Current date is 2021-05-17T09:06:57.239015+00:00 and task will be retried at 2021-05-17T09:09:50.662150+00:00.
```

am i missing something to judge if it is a bug or if it is expected?

`addition`, below is the DAG definition as requested.

```
import airflow
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.contrib.operators.databricks_operator import DatabricksSubmitRunOperator
from airflow.models import Variable

dag_args = {
    "owner": "our_project_team_name",
    "retries": 1,
    "email": ["ouremail_address_replaced_by_this_string"],
    "email_on_failure": True,
    "email_on_retry": True,
    "depends_on_past": False,
    "start_date": airflow.utils.dates.days_ago(1),
}
# Implement cluster reuse on Databricks, pick from light, medium, heavy cluster type based on workloads
clusters = Variable.get("our_project_team_namejob_cluster_config", deserialize_json=True)

databricks_connection = "our_company_databricks"
adl_connection = "our_company_wasb"

pipeline_name = "process_our_data_from_boomi"

dag = DAG(dag_id=pipeline_name, default_args=dag_args, schedule_interval="0 3 * * *")

notebook_dir = "/Shared/our_data_name"
lib_path_sub = ""
lib_name_dev_plus_branch = ""
atlas_library = {
    "whl": f"dbfs:/python-wheels/atlas{lib_path_sub}/atlas_library-0{lib_name_dev_plus_branch}-py3-none-any.whl"
}

create_our_data_name_source_data_from_boomi_notebook_params = {
    "existing_cluster_id": clusters["our_cluster_name"],
    "notebook_task": {
        "notebook_path": f"{notebook_dir}/create_our_data_name_source_data_from_boomi",
        "base_parameters": {"Extraction_date": "{{ ds_nodash  }}"},
    },
}

create_our_data_name_standardized_table_from_source_xml_notebook_params = {
    "existing_cluster_id": clusters["our_cluster_name"],
    "notebook_task": {
        "notebook_path": f"{notebook_dir}/create_our_data_name_standardized_table_from_source_xml",
        "base_parameters": {"Extraction_date": "{{ ds_nodash  }}"},
    },
}

create_our_data_name_enriched_table_from_standardized_notebook_params = {
    "existing_cluster_id": clusters["our_cluster_name"],
    "notebook_task": {
        "notebook_path": f"{notebook_dir}/create_our_data_name_enriched",
        "base_parameters": {"Extraction_date": "{{ ds_nodash  }}"},
    },
}

layer_1_task = DatabricksSubmitRunOperator(
    task_id="Load_our_data_name_to_source",
    databricks_conn_id=databricks_connection,
    dag=dag,
    json=create_our_data_name_source_data_from_boomi_notebook_params,
    libraries=[atlas_library],
)

layer_2_task = DatabricksSubmitRunOperator(
    task_id="Load_our_data_name_to_standardized",
    databricks_conn_id=databricks_connection,
    dag=dag,
    json=create_our_data_name_standardized_table_from_source_xml_notebook_params,
    libraries=[
        {"maven": {"coordinates": "com.databricks:spark-xml_2.11:0.5.0"}},
        {"pypi": {"package": "inflection"}},
        atlas_library,
    ],
)

layer_3_task = DatabricksSubmitRunOperator(
    task_id="Load_our_data_name_to_enriched",
    databricks_conn_id=databricks_connection,
    dag=dag,
    json=create_our_data_name_enriched_table_from_standardized_notebook_params,
    libraries=[atlas_library],
)

layer_1_task >> layer_2_task >> layer_3_task
```

Comment: could you share the airflow schedule and how you are configuring them?

Comment: @anand where/how do I get the airflow schedule? Do you mean how often it runs? Daily. 3:00UTC

Comment: could you paste the DAG config - the python code?

Comment: @AnandVidvat, please see added DAG definition. sorry i am a bit late in providing this.

Comment: Could you set the `retries` argument in your `default_args` as 0 and try ?

Comment: @AnandVidvat, I've tried to change the retries to 0, and as expected, it goes to the lifecycle "queueue" -> "failed". there is no log to indicate why it failed. `Dependency Reason Task Instance State Task is in the 'failed' state which is not a valid state for execution. The task must be cleared in order to be run`. and this `queued_dttm 2021-07-10 07:09:26.052548+00:00.`. Of course, after clear the state, it runs successfully, just like before this change, it will just show `up for retry` and then it will just run successfully when retries.

Comment: you might be able to use `databricks_retry_delay` argument to some thing like 60 (means 60 seconds) to understand what is happing in between your trigger/start DAG and failed state. reference : https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-databricks/stable/_api/airflow/providers/databricks/operators/databricks/index.html?highlight=databrickssubmitrunoperator#airflow.providers.databricks.operators.databricks.DatabricksSubmitRunOperator

Comment: thanks @AnandVidvat. I've decided after talking to some of my friends, to test using DumyOperator or PythonOperator to eliminate causes. and the conclusion is that this has nothing to do with the databrcks operator. it is somehow which i need to further investigate related to our airflow setup. I will post an 'answer' to the question to indicate it is not bug of airflow, with my test details. current retry_delay for DAG is 5 mins, and my workaround for the issue is to set it to 10 seconds. because the retry always suceed, the 1st run alwys fail without log and put into `up for retry`

Answer (score 1):

after getting some help from @AnandVidvat about trying to make retry=0 experiment and some firend help to change operator to either DummyOperator or PythonOperator, i can confirm that **the issue is not to do with DatabricksOperator or airflow version 1.10.x**. i.e it is not an airflow bug.

so in summary, when a DAG, has meaningful operator, my setup fails in first Execution without any task log, and during **retry** works OK (the task log hides the fact it had been retried, because the failure had no logs).

In order to reduce the total run time. The workaround/patch, before finding the real cause, is to set the `retry_delay` to 10 seconds (default is 5 mins, and it makes DAG run long unnessicssarily.)

Next step is to figure out what is causing this 1st failure thing, by checking logs on scheduler or woker pods in our current setup (azure K8s, postgresql, Redis, celery executor).

p.s. I used below DAG tested and get the conclusion.

```
import airflow
from airflow import DAG

from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
import time
from pprint import pprint

dag_args = {
    "owner": "min_test",
    "retries": 1,
    "email": ["c243d70b.domain.onmicrosoft.com@emea.teams.ms"],
    "email_on_failure": True,
    "email_on_retry": True,
    "depends_on_past": False,
    "start_date": airflow.utils.dates.days_ago(1),
}

pipeline_name = "min_test_debug_airflow_baseline_PythonOperator_1_retry"

dag = DAG(
    dag_id=pipeline_name,
    default_args=dag_args,
    schedule_interval="0 3 * * *",
    tags=["min_test_airflow"],
)


def my_sleeping_function(random_base):
    """This is a function that will run within the DAG execution"""
    time.sleep(random_base)


def print_context(ds, **kwargs):
    pprint(kwargs)
    print(ds)
    return "Whatever you return gets printed in the logs"


run_this = PythonOperator(
    task_id="print_the_context",
    provide_context=True,
    python_callable=print_context,
    dag=dag,
)

# Generate 3 sleeping tasks, sleeping from 0 to 2 seconds respectively
for i in range(3):
    task = PythonOperator(
        task_id="sleep_for_" + str(i),
        python_callable=my_sleeping_function,
        op_kwargs={"random_base": float(i) / 10},
        dag=dag,
    )

    task.set_upstream(run_this)
```

Comment: but we are still not sure what has caused this behaviour, something in our setup/deployment is wrong. will update here when one day we found the cause.